# Saving multiple JSON objects in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have parameters like this:

```
    Parameters: {
"map"=>[
{"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396522", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:00"}, 
{"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396453", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:01"}, 
{"lat"=>"51.088829", "lon"=>"71.396476", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:14"}
]}
```

and strong params defined:

```
def map_params
  params.permit( map: [:lat,:lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent])
end
```

How to save all of my 3 objects in rails controller method. I can do that for 1 object but not for 3.

EDIT: for saving one object I use:

```
params.require(:map).permit(:lat, :lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent)
```

But, I guess this wouldn't work for multiple objects.

Comment: What's wrong with `params.permit( map: [:lat,:lon, :vibration_level, :time_sent])`?

Comment: @NitishParkar, params are permitted, I guess, but how to save them? does rails do it automatically if i call '@'map = Map.new(map_params);  map.save

Comment: Do you want to save them all in a single record or do you want to create 3 map records?

Comment: @NitishParkar, 3 map records

Comment: Please post code of the controller action you are using to create records.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285093/create-multiple-entries-with-checkbox-and-strong-params-in-rails4

Comment: @NitishParkar, i don't know how to save them. I guess i have to traverse params and save them one by one. But also I guess rails should have some smart autosave of multiple objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the basic way to create multiple record at a time with rails,

```
  maps = Map.create([
              {"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396522", vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:00"}, 
              {"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396453", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:01"},
              {"lat"=>"51.088829", "lon"=>"71.396476", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:14"}
  ])
```

You can use your map_params for creating all maps at time as following

```
maps = Map.create(map_params["map"])
```

Comment: Looks, like nothing happens.    (0.1ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction

Comment: trace what is return by `map_params`, data format should be as in above example, if not re-write your `def map_params`.

Comment: sorry i am a new to rails, how can i trace?

Comment: past this `puts map_params` before `Map.create(map_params)`, and observer development log.

Comment: get my params printed out.

Comment: whats that ? Past here please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80530/discussion-between-rokibul-hasan-and-yerassyl).

Comment: {"map"=>[{"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396522", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:00"}, {"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396453", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:01"}, {"lat"=>"51.088829", "lon"=>"71.396476", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:14"}]}

Comment: Can you please print this `puts map_params["map"]`, if it returns `[{"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396522", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:00"}, {"lat"=>"51.088672", "lon"=>"71.396453", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:01"}, {"lat"=>"51.088829", "lon"=>"71.396476", "vibration_level"=>"300", "time_sent"=>"07:25:14"}]` then use `Map.create(map_params["map"])`, let me if works?

Comment: @Rakibul Hasan, yes it worked. Thank you very much. Edit your answer i will accept it.